# Adapt a function in TypeScript, with type checking

Tags: typescript

I'd like to adapt a number of existing functions, with differing signatures, yet maintain the type / signature checking of the original.

For example:

```
const functionOne = (name: string, age: number) => ({
    name,
    age
})

const functionTwo = (name: string, sex: string) =>  ({
    name,
    sex
})

const addIndexToReturn = (adaptee: any, index: number) =>
  (...args: any[]) => 
    Object.assign(adaptee(...args), { index })

const functionWithIndex = addIndexToReturn(functionOne, 22)

// I don't get any type checking here
console.log(functionWithIndex('Frank', 32))
```

As you can see, I have a number of functions that return various different objects. I have a function addIndexToReturn that adapts these, returning a new function that adds an index to their returned value.

However, the new function doesn't have any type checking on its parameters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the number of arguments in `adaptee` constant (2)? or at least limited (<3, <4...)?

Comment: the adapted can have any signature

Comment: Then I don't see how that can be defined

Comment: `const functionWithIndex = addIndexToReturn(functionOne)` causes a type error. You haven't supplied the index parameter. What are you hoping to do?

Comment: I don't think that you'll be able to do that with type checking without changing your design. But, why not the other way around? Can't you do: `addIndex(functionOne("Frank", 32), 5)`?

Comment: @Paarth - sorry, I've updated the code and tested it in the playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: Did you see my answer? I'm curious about if that did not work for you.

Comment: @Alex yes - see comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work using the trick from LINQ -

```
interface Adapter {
    <A, T>(adaptee: (a: A) => T): (a: A) => T;
    <A, B, T>(adaptee: (a: A, b: B) => T): (a: A, b: B) => T; 
}

const fn = (x: String): String => x + y.toString();
const fn2 = (x: String, y: Number): String => x + y.toString();

const adapt: Adapter = (adaptee) => adaptee;    

adapt(fn)(1)
adapt(fn)("")
adapt(fn2)(1, 2)
adapt(fn2)("", 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're throwing away the type information of the parameter function because your return lambda takes in `any[]`

You could attempt to handle the issue with something like this:

```
type Indexed<T> = T & { index: number };
function addIndexToReturn<T, V>(func: (param: T) => V, index: number) : (param:T) => Indexed<V> {
    return (x:T) => {
        let result = func(x) as Indexed<V>;
        result.index = index;
        return result;
    }
}
```

But this only works for single-parameter functions. I don't believe you can express this correctly for function with arbitrary values for reasons similar to [my other recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37264390/2557260).

> If we are to handle the case of variable length parameters, we must
>   treat the parameters as a **Collection**. Because all variables must
>   have a single (though possibly parameterized) type so too must this
>   collection object. However, the types of the various functions do not
>   align. `(param:A) => B` is not the same type as `(param:B) => C` and
>   cannot be stored in the same well typed container (barring union types
>   but those won't scale either).

Comment: I guess this could be solved with repeated definitions of `addIndexToReturn`, each with an additional parameter, similar to the way C# defines delegate types? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289012(v=vs.110).aspx