# Typescript typings in chained calls

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, linked-list, method-chaining

#### UPDATE:

- better explanation of what I seek
- partial examples of what I tried
- reduction of the issue to an injection problem

## My issue

I'm trying to write some pattern that would allow an object to extend another object without class inheritance, to achieve loose coupling and a functional approach (what I represent by the "extend" function in my sample, which could also be called "pipe"). Which is easy. But all of that while preserving the typings. Which is hard.

I'm wondering how to get Typescript typings follow the flow.

Here is a simplified code segment, for the example ([link for Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20DecoratorAbstract%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20parent%3A%20DecoratorAbstract%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20extend%3CT%20extends%20DecoratorAbstract%3E(decorator%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20decorator.parent%20%3D%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20decorator%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20decorate()%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20InitialDecorator%20extends%20DecoratorAbstract%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20decorate()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20var%3A%20'value'%20%7D%20as%20%7B%20'var'%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Decorator1%20extends%20DecoratorAbstract%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20decorate()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20result%20%3D%20this.parent.decorate()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20newResult%20%3D%20Object.assign(result%2C%20%7B%20'foo'%3A%20'foo'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20newResult%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Decorator2%20extends%20DecoratorAbstract%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20decorate()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20result%20%3D%20this.parent.decorate()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20newResult%20%3D%20Object.assign(result%2C%20%7B%20'bar'%3A%20'bar'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20newResult%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Split%20to%20show%20the%20return%20types%20%0D%0Alet%20initialDecorator%20%3D%20new%20InitialDecorator()%3B%0D%0Alet%20r0%20%3D%20initialDecorator.decorate()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20decorator1%20%3D%20initialDecorator.extend(new%20Decorator1)%3B%0D%0Alet%20r1%20%3D%20decorator1.decorate()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20decorator2%20%3D%20decorator1.extend(new%20Decorator2)%3B%0D%0Alet%20r2%20%3D%20decorator2.decorate()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(r2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20The%20syntax%20I%20seek%0D%0Alet%20someDecorator%20%3D%20new%20InitialDecorator()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.extend(new%20Decorator1)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.extend(new%20Decorator2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20someResult%20%3D%20someDecorator.decorate()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20The%20type%20I%20seek%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7Bvar%3A%20string%7D%20%26%20%7Bfoo%3A%20string%7D%20%26%20%7Bbar%3A%20string%7D)):

```
abstract class DecoratorAbstract {
    public parent: DecoratorAbstract;

    public extend<T extends DecoratorAbstract>(decorator: T): T {
        decorator.parent = this;
        return decorator;
    }

    abstract decorate(): {}
}

class InitialDecorator extends DecoratorAbstract {
    decorate() {
        return { var: 'value' } as { 'var': string };
    }
}

class Decorator1 extends DecoratorAbstract {
    decorate() {
        let result = this.parent.decorate();
        let newResult = Object.assign(result, { 'foo': 'foo' });
        return newResult;
    }
}

class Decorator2 extends DecoratorAbstract {
    decorate() {
        let result = this.parent.decorate();
        let newResult = Object.assign(result, { 'bar': 'bar' });
        return newResult;
    }
}

// Split to show the return types 
let initialDecorator = new InitialDecorator();
let r0 = initialDecorator.decorate();

let decorator1 = initialDecorator.extend(new Decorator1);
let r1 = decorator1.decorate();

let decorator2 = decorator1.extend(new Decorator2);
let r2 = decorator2.decorate();

console.log(r2);

// The syntax I seek
let someDecorator = new InitialDecorator()
    .extend(new Decorator1);
    .extend(new Decorator2);

let someResult = someDecorator.decorate();
// The type I seek:
// {var: string} & {foo: string} & {bar: string}
```

The typings I get:
`{} & {'foo': string;}` for `r1` and `{} & {'bar': string;}`for `r2`, replacing the returned type of `decorator.parent.decorate` by `{}` (result of the abstract function) instead of the real type.

So I'm wondering:

1. Is what I try to do possible?
2. If not, why?
3. If yes, is there a solution something not syntactically too horrible (and  following that concept or something close)

---

## UPDATE: The things I tried

#### With a factory

```
public extend<T extends DecoratorAbstract>(decoratorName: { new (): T }) {
   let decorator = new decoratorName();
   decorator.parent = this;
   return decorator;
}
```

#### To use some *Piper* object

```
class Piper<T extends {parent: PARENT}, PARENT> {
    public obj: T;
    public parent: PARENT;

    constructor(obj: T, parent: PARENT) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.obj.parent = this.parent as PARENT;
    }

    out(): T {
        return this.obj;
    }
}
```

#### To use a collection

But my collection objects type has to be known at the beginning and the same for all the items. Maybe I didn't do it the right way.

#### Linked List approach

That is working:

```
class Link<OBJ, PARENTLINK> {
    constructor(public obj: OBJ, public parent:PARENTLINK = null) {}

    pipe<NEWOBJ>(newObj: NEWOBJ):Link<NEWOBJ, this> {
        return new Link(newObj, this);
    }
}

abstract class DecoratorAbstract {
    abstract decorate<T>(result: T): {}
}

class InitialDecorator extends DecoratorAbstract {
    decorate<T>(result:T) {
        return { var: 'value' } as { 'var': string };
    }
}

class Decorator1 extends DecoratorAbstract {
    decorate<T>(result:T) {
        let newResult = Object.assign(result, { 'foo': 'foo' });
        return newResult;
    }
}

class Decorator2 extends DecoratorAbstract {
    decorate<T>(result:T) {
        let newResult = Object.assign(result, { 'bar': 'bar' });
        return newResult;
    }
}

let l = new Link(new InitialDecorator);
let l1 = l.pipe(new Decorator1);
let l2 = l1.pipe(new Decorator2);
```

I can create a chain of objects and preserve their types.
But it doesn't help so much...
As soon as the **this** word is encountered, the typings don't follow anymore (fall back on the Abstract class).

## So far...

I didn't succeed to make *Typescript* retain my object type yet. Mainly because:

- generic types have to be clearly defined on object declaration
- class type is specific (*Typescript* doesn't follow the the object inheritance model when analyzing the return types)

I think my issue could be solved by a way to design a Linked List or a Collection that would preserve the typings of each element.

---

## UPDATE: reduction of the issue to an injection problem

I think my attempts were close to a solution...

But the problem I always fall back on is the following ([test it in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20BaseObj%3CP%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20parent%3A%20P%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20test()%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%3CP%20extends%20BaseObj%3Cany%3E%3E%20extends%20BaseObj%3CP%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.parent.test()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%3CP%20extends%20BaseObj%3Cany%3E%3E%20extends%20BaseObj%3CP%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bhop%3A%20'la'%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20let%20c%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20Won't%20work%20%0D%0Alet%20c%20%3D%20new%20A%3CB%3Cany%3E%3E()%3B%0D%0Ac.parent%20%3D%20new%20B%3B%0D%0Ac.parent.test()%3B%20%2F%2F%20return%20type%3A%20%7Bhop%3A%20string%7D)):

```
abstract class BaseObj<P> { 
    parent: P
    abstract test(): {}
}

class A<P extends BaseObj<any>> extends BaseObj<P> {
    test() { 
        return this.parent.test();
    }   
}

class B<P extends BaseObj<any>> extends BaseObj<P> {
    test() {
        return {hop: 'la'};
    }
}

// let c = new A();  // Won't work 
let c = new A<B<any>>();
c.parent = new B;
c.parent.test(); // return type: {hop: string}
```

The problem is simple: I'd want the object `A` to call the method of an injected object `B` (in the following case, the injected object is embedded).

For that to be feasible in a general way:

- `A` must be aware of the type of `B`, otherwise it will use the type it extends
- For that, I must be able to specify the generic type, or to ensure the object detects it

It works in this example, because everything is very concrete, but instead of:

```
let c = new A<B<any>>();
c.parent = new B;
```

what I want is some function to allow injecting the class/object, this way:

`pipe(MyObj, new InjectedObj());` or `let a = pipe(new MyObj(), new InjectedObj());`

The issue is that I didn't manage to return out of the `pipe` function an instance of `A` that is typed as `A<B<any>>`, always `A<any>`...

Detecting the types in entry of `pipe` is not an issue. But getting an object aware of the other (injected) object type is where I always fail...

Whatever the way I write it, fall back on a problem apparented to this one.

---

My attempts:

- with a generic for the method return values ([test it in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20TestInterface%3CASOBJECT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asObject()%3AASOBJECT%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20BaseObject%3CPARENT_ASOBJECT%3E%20implements%20TestInterface%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20parent%3A%20TestInterface%3CPARENT_ASOBJECT%3E%20%3D%20null%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20pipe%3CSELF%2C%20ASOB%3E(this%3A%20SELF%20%26%20TestInterface%3CASOB%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20obj%20%3D%20new%20Obj2(10)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj.parent%20%3D%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20obj%20as%20Obj2%3CASOB%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20asObject()%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Obj%3CPARENT_ASOBJECT%3E%20extends%20BaseObject%3CPARENT_ASOBJECT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20n%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asObject()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bvalue%3A%20this.n%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Obj2%3CPARENT_ASOBJECT%3E%20extends%20BaseObject%3CPARENT_ASOBJECT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20n%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asObject()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(this.parent.asObject()%2C%20%7Bval2%3A%20this.n%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20new%20Obj(5)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2Flet%20obj2%20%3D%20obj.pipe(new%20Obj2(10))%3B%0D%0Alet%20obj2%20%3D%20obj.pipe()%3B%0D%0Alet%20r%20%3D%20obj2.asObject()%3B))
- with a factory: [test it...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Store%3CT%2C%20PARENT%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20inf%3A%20T%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(ctor%3A%20%7B%20new%20(store%3A%20Store%3CT%2C%20PARENT%3E)%3A%20T%20%7D%2C%20public%20parent%3A%20PARENT%20%3D%20null)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.inf%20%3D%20new%20ctor(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyStore%3CT%20extends%20Inf%2C%20PARENT%20extends%20Store%3Cany%2C%20any%3E%3E%20extends%20Store%3CT%2C%20PARENT%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20%7B%20new%20(store%3A%20Store%3Cany%2C%20any%3E)%3A%20T%20%7D%2C%20parent%3A%20PARENT%20%3D%20null)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(name%2C%20parent)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20pipe%3CU%20extends%20Inf%2C%20SELF%20extends%20Store%3Cany%2C%20any%3E%20%3E(this%3A%20SELF%2C%20name%3A%20%7B%20new%20(store%3A%20Store%3Cany%2C%20any%3E)%3A%20U%20%7D)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20MyStore%3CU%2C%20SELF%3E(name%2C%20this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20Inf%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20store%3A%20Store%3Cany%2C%20any%3E)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20test()%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Inf1%20extends%20Inf%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20hop%3A%20'hop'%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Inf2%20extends%20Inf%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.store%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Inf3%20extends%20Inf%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20li%3A%20'li'%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20store%20%3D%20new%20MyStore(Inf1)%3B%0D%0Alet%20r1%20%3D%20store.test()%0D%0Alet%20store2%20%3D%20store.pipe(Inf2)%3B%0D%0Alet%20p1%20%3D%20store2.parent%3B%0D%0Alet%20r2%20%3D%20store2.inf.test()%3B%0D%0Alet%20store3%20%3D%20store2.pipe(Inf3)%3B%0D%0Alet%20p2%20%3D%20store3.parent%3B%0D%0Alet%20r3%20%3D%20store3.inf.test()%3B%0D%0A)
- with abstract classes but no generic for the method returns: [test it...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20ObjAbstract%3CPARENT%20extends%20ObjAbstract%3Cany%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20parent%3A%20PARENT%20%3D%20null)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20test()%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getParent()%3APARENT%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.parent%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20ObjBuilder%3CPARENT%20extends%20ObjAbstract%3Cany%3E%3E%20extends%20ObjAbstract%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(parent%3A%20PARENT%20%3D%20null)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(parent%20as%20PARENT)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20pipe%3CSELF%20extends%20ObjAbstract%3Cany%3E%2C%20T%20extends%20ObjAbstract%3Cany%3E%3E(this%3A%20SELF%2C%20obj%3A%20%7B%20new%20(parent%3A%20ObjAbstract%3CSELF%3E)%3A%20T%20%7D)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20obj(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Obj%20extends%20ObjBuilder%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bhop%3A%20'hop'%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Obj2%20extends%20ObjBuilder%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(this.getParent().test()%20%2C%20%7Bla%3A%20'la'%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myObject%20%3D%20new%20Obj()%3B%0D%0Alet%20v%20%3D%20myObject.test()%3B%0D%0Alet%20myObject2%20%3D%20myObject.pipe(Obj2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20p%20%3D%20myObject2.getParent()%3B%0D%0Alet%20v2%20%3D%20myObject2.test()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)
- getting closer by rebuilding an interface: [test it...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Methods%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20BaseObj%20implements%20Methods%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20parent%3A%20BaseObj%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20test()%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20BaseObj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.parent.test()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20BaseObj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bhop%3A%20'la'%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Ob%3CPARENT%2C%20OBJ%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20parent%3A%20PARENT%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%3A%20OBJ%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20cross%3CPARENT%2C%20SELF%3E(self%3A%20SELF%2C%20parent%3A%20PARENT)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20obj%3A%20Ob%3CPARENT%2C%20SELF%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20parent%3A%20parent%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%3A%20self%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20obj%20as%20Ob%3CPARENT%2C%20SELF%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20cross(new%20A%2C%20new%20B)%3B%0D%0Aa.obj.test()%0D%0Alet%20abis%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Comment: Can't give you a full answer at the moment. This is doable, but you could achieve something (IMO) cleaner by taking advantage of the fact that javascript has higher order functions, unlike other OOP languages which may necessitate this pattern. This is an answer I wrote to an unrelated question, but has a code sample you may find interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263773/how-should-the-lodash-flow-function-be-typed-in-typescript/37264390#37264390

Comment: Interesting, piping is indeed what I try to do (and my "extend" function was named "pipe" in the original code). In this case there can be more than one "decorate" functions. I'm not too attached to the design, rather trying to redesign something that works with a way to preserve the types. Typescript, by applying an Object paradigm over a prototype oriented language, somewhat forces me to do things in an heavier way than what pure JS with a functional approach would provide. I'll have a deeper look at your sample when I'll have more time, in a few days.

Comment: @Paarth Your example about the function composition was inspiring. I tried to apply the concept at the class level. But with no success...

Comment: I didn't get the "`A` must be aware of the type `B`". `B` is called from `A` even if the type is `A<BaseObj<any>>`. Is it a problem?

Comment: @RodrigoPedrosa Yes, for typings. What I was looking for was a way to compose typings. To chain/pipe some objects extending BaseObj (to obtain a composed object), and for their common functions, to return a composed return type. And thanks to type inference, no explicit generic declaration (it's part of a larger design, this part in an isolated problem).

Comment: Looks like [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) or [Mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html). Are these not enough?

Comment: @RodrigoPedrosa Yes, sorry, I meant intersection and not union... The question is: how to return that (without declaring the final type explicitely)... When it comes to typings, if an object embeds another object, the embedded object definition will be the definition of the abstract/base object. I should have a look at TS 2.4 new features, there are some evolutions concerning type inference.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript can't know the return type `A<B<any>>` if it is not defined anywhere. If you want to mount the pipes at runtime, it will only know its type at runtime.

How about to make it defined as the final return, like `A<string>`? It could still call `B`, but, at the end, what matters is that the final result will be a string.

```
type PipeConstructor<TOut, TIn> = { new(): Pipe<TOut, TIn> };

abstract class PipeEnd<TOut> {
    abstract test(): TOut;
}

abstract class Pipe<TOut, TIn> extends PipeEnd<TOut> {
    parent: PipeEnd<TIn>;

    static mount<TOut extends T, T>(...pipes: PipeConstructor<T, T>[]): PipeEnd<TOut> {
        let pipeEnd: Pipe<TOut, T>;
        let pipe: Pipe<T, T>;
        let pipePrevious: Pipe<T, T>;

        for (var pipeConstructor of pipes) {
            pipe = new pipeConstructor();
            if (!pipeEnd) pipeEnd = <Pipe<TOut, T>>pipe;
            if (pipePrevious) {
                pipePrevious.parent = pipe;
            }
            pipePrevious = pipe;
        }

        return pipeEnd;
    }
}

class A extends Pipe<string, string> {
    test() {
        return this.parent.test().toString();
    }
}

class B extends Pipe<string, number> {
    test() {
        return this.parent.test().toString();
    }
}

class C extends Pipe<number, void> {
    test() {
        return 123;
    }
}

let pipe = Pipe.mount<string, number | string | void>(A, B, C);

console.dir(pipe); // A.B.C
console.log(pipe.test()); // 123
```

Comment: Thanks for having shared interest I've let this issue aside for some time...
The idea was to extend objects, and also to extend their result thanks to type inference (by cumulating the resulting object structure with unions). Specifying the type is precisley what I try to avoid (or I wouldn't have posted on Stack Overflow).
I wasn't so far, if only that would have worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688748/typescript-how-to-return-the-proper-class-and-generic-type-in-a-dependency

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to manage the generics with a minimalist functional approach:

```
const decorate1 = <T>(item: T) => Object.assign({}, item, { b: 'b' })
const decorate2 = <T>(item: T) => Object.assign({}, item, { c: 'c' })
const multiDecorate = <T>(item: T) => decorate2(decorate1(item));

const initial = { a: 'a' };
const multiDecorated = multiDecorate(initial);

console.log({ multiDecorated });
```

[Try it in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20decorate1%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(item%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20item%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%20'b'%20%7D)%0D%0Aconst%20decorate2%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(item%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20item%2C%20%7B%20c%3A%20'c'%20%7D)%0D%0Aconst%20multiDecorate%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(item%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20decorate2(decorate1(item))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20initial%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20'a'%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20multiDecorated%20%3D%20multiDecorate(initial)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%7B%20multiDecorated%20%7D)%3B)

The type flows through so that `multiDecorated` is the intersection type:

```
{} & { a: string; } & { b: string; } & { c: string; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not what I'm looking for. I updated my example to be more accurate.