# Typescript: how to return the proper class and generic type in a dependency

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, typescript-typings

I'm trying to find a way to inject an object into another object (dependency injection), in which the container object can return *the proper injected **object type***, and *no need to explicitly pass types to the function* (type inference).
To make sure the injected objects have a common interface and a default behavior, they'd be instances of an Abstract class.

Given that I'd need such a behavior at some ponctual place, I would like to avoid using a dependency injection framework to do so.

> It seems to me that what I need is to set the generic type on object instantiation because generic parameters cannot be redefined afterwards. Consequently I'd need to use a **factory** (`new()` interface)

---

Here is an example. [Test it in Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20ArrayClassAbstract%3CMYTYPE%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20arr%3A%20Array%3CMYTYPE%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(element%3A%20MYTYPE)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.arr.push(element)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ArrayClass%3CMYTYPE%3E%20extends%20ArrayClassAbstract%3CMYTYPE%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.arr%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SomeOtherArrayClass%3CMYTYPE%3E%20extends%20ArrayClassAbstract%3CMYTYPE%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.arr%20%2B%20%22something%20different%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createMyClass%3CMYTYPE%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(className%3A%20%7B%20new%20%3CMYTYPE%3E(element%3A%20MYTYPE)%3A%20ArrayClassAbstract%3CMYTYPE%3E%20%7D%2C%20element%3A%20MYTYPE)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20className%3CMYTYPE%3E(element)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20createMyClass(ArrayClass%2C%20%22hop!%22)%3B%20%20%20%2F%2F%20type%3A%20%7BArrayClassAbstract%3Cstring%3E%7D%0D%0Aa.test()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Doesn't%20work...%20%22test%22%20doesn't%20exist%20in%20ArrayClassAbstract%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createMyClass2%3CT%20extends%20ArrayClassAbstract%3Cstring%3E%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(className%3A%20%7B%20new%20(element%3A%20string)%3A%20T%20%7D%2C%20element%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20className(element)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20createMyClass2(ArrayClass%2C%20%22hop!%22)%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20type%3A%20%7BArrayClass%3Cany%3E%7D%0D%0Ab.test()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Works%20but%20array%20elements%20typed%20as%20%22any%22). To make things simple, I'm looking for `createMyClass2` to return an object typed `ArrayClass<string>`, without specifying the type explicitly when calling it (type inference).
It may be considered that `ArrayClass` and `ArrayClassAbstract` are some kind of plugins defined in different *NPM* modules for example.

```
class ArrayClassAbstract<MYTYPE> {
    public arr: Array<MYTYPE> = []
    constructor(element: MYTYPE) {
        this.arr.push(element);
    }
}

class ArrayClass<MYTYPE> extends ArrayClassAbstract<MYTYPE> {
    test() { 
        return this.arr;
    }
}

class SomeOtherArrayClass<MYTYPE> extends ArrayClassAbstract<MYTYPE> {
    test() { 
        return this.arr + "something different";
    }
}

function createMyClass<MYTYPE>
    (className: { new <MYTYPE>(element: MYTYPE): ArrayClassAbstract<MYTYPE> }, element: MYTYPE) { 
    return new className<MYTYPE>(element);
}

let a = createMyClass(ArrayClass, "hop!");   // type: {ArrayClassAbstract<string>}
a.test();                                    // Doesn't work... "test" doesn't exist in ArrayClassAbstract
```

Good generic type, wrong class type...

```
function createMyClass2<T extends ArrayClassAbstract<string>>
    (className: { new (element: string): T }, element: string) { 
    return new className(element);
}

let b = createMyClass2(ArrayClass, "hop!");  // type: {ArrayClass<any>}
b.test();                                    // Works but array elements typed as "any"
```

Good class type, wrong generic type.
I don't know if there's something wrong in my way to declare the factory, or if I'm victim of Typescript limitations...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

How about using overloads?

```
function createMyClass2<MYTYPE>(type: typeof ArrayClass, element: MYTYPE): ArrayClass<MYTYPE>;
function createMyClass2<MYTYPE>(type: typeof SomeOtherArrayClass, element: MYTYPE): SomeOtherArrayClass<MYTYPE>;
function createMyClass2(className, element) {
    return new className(element);
}

let b = createMyClass2(ArrayClass, "hop!");  // type: {ArrayClass<string>}
b.test();
let c = createMyClass2(ArrayClass, 123);  // type: {ArrayClass<number>}
c.test();
let d = createMyClass2(SomeOtherArrayClass, "hop!");  // type: {SomeOtherArrayClass<string>}
d.test();
```

Comment: This is about dependency injection

Comment: Woops! Can't change my vote until you edit your answer... I could +1 this one. Although that's not perfect for a factory, and I'd have troubles at integrating that as the final solution, the idea is not bad

Comment: @arvymetal Removed the unnecessary type. Maybe, you could provide more details of your needs in your question?

Comment: You're right, I think my question isn't very clear. I've just tried to improve it. I don't want to give too much context, I think it would be more confusing, And thanks for your interest ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just need a second type parameter. It can still be inferred:

```
// Renamed some stuff for clarity
type ConstructorFor<CtorArg, Inst> = { new(element: CtorArg): Inst; }; 
function createMyClass<CtorArg, InstType extends ArrayClassAbstract<CtorArg>>(ctor: ConstructorFor<CtorArg, InstType>, arg: CtorArg) { 
    return new ctor(arg);
}

let a = createMyClass(ArrayClass, "hop!");   // type: {ArrayClass<string>}
a.test(); // OK
```

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? For 2.3, `arr` is inferred as `any[]`: if you add `let x: void = a.arr[0];` you will get no error, and playground shows `let a: ArrayClass<any>` in the tooltip, not `ArrayClass<string>`

Comment: @ryan-cavanaugh Errr... As @artem says, it doesn't work. At least on TS Playground.
In fact, this way to do is similar to what I did with my second block of code "Good class type, wrong generic type", except that I hard coded the `string` type rather than passing it through `Inst` (it returns `any`...).
I'm also a buyer of other solutions (like a wrapper class) but I have the feeling I tried it all... 

No way to force typing to be implicit/auto in the parent class or stuff like that? To use an intermediate function? To reassign a generic? Something I wouldn't be aware of that could help?

Comment: By the way, to give more context, I try to write an object chained list (an object holds its parent), in which the object methods can reference the parent (and they all have the same base type). It seemed legitimate, I didn't imagine such patterns would be so hard to type.